# Facebook Auth Error

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, passport.js

it will be great if someone can help me with this and I have researched for countless hours on stack overflow already
[This is my login page​​](https://yelp-camp-tommyschool.c9users.io/login)

When I click on the facebook button, it takes me to /auth/facebook​
Then after that, I get redirected to a 
ECONNRESET: Request could not be proxied!
There was an error proxying the request error.

In the terminal, it says:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y21G2.png)
​
How do I fix this? PS.

Going off this tutorial
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-facebook​

Also Im using node.js, MongoDB, express.js, and facebook

Much thanks and have an amazing day

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. Relevant code and relevant error messages belong directly into your question, in text form, and not just as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error that I'm seeing when trying to authenticate your app via Facebook, it seems as if your domain URL has not been properly added to [Facebook's Developer API](https://developers.facebook.com).

Are the proper URL's entered for your Facebook **App Domains** (in **Basic Settings**) and **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** (in **Facebook Login** Settings)?

Also, regarding that Node error that you're receiving, what is on **line 60** of your **Passport.js** file?